.NET Core - Protect entire Swagger UI with Microsoft.Identity.Web
I've built an api in .NET Core for my org and have secured the endpoints behind a MSAL OAuth2 flow with PKCE. I'd like to prepare in the event that the api should be accessed by 3rd parties. The api itself is accessible via a Bearer token but I'd like to secure the Swagger UI as well (accessing /swagger/index.html should redirect to the same OAuth2 flow used by the Authorize button) to prevent unauthorized access to the documentation.
Here's the current setup:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using System.Net;

namespace WebAPI.SomeNamespace
{
    public class SwaggerAzureAdAuthMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate next;
        public SwaggerAzureAdAuthMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            this.next = next;
        }

        public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
        {
            if (context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/swagger") && !context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                await context.ChallengeAsync(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
                return;
            }

            await next.Invoke(context);
        }
    }

    public static class SwaggerAuthExtensions
    {
        public static IApplicationBuilder UseSwaggerAzureAdAuth(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
        {
            return builder.UseMiddleware<SwaggerAzureAdAuthMiddleware>();
        }
    }
}

Startup.cs extract
//...
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) 
{
    //...
    services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(_configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
            .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
            .AddMicrosoftGraph(_configuration.GetSection("MicrosoftGraph"))
            .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
    //...
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    //...
        app.UseSwaggerAzureAdAuth();
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
        {
                options.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "API v1");
                options.OAuthClientId(_configuration.GetValue<string>("AzureAd:ClientId"));
                options.OAuthScopes(_configuration.GetValue<string>("AzureAd:Scopes"));
                options.OAuthUsePkce();
        });
    //...
}
//...

It's definitely wrong but can't find out how to make it right. From what I gathered, await context.ChallengeAsync() should have triggered the flow specified in services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme) but I might have misunderstood this because this line doesn't seem to be doing anything when debugging.

Swashbuckle has built-in configuration for integrateing Azure AD auth scheme so that we could test API protected by Azure AD through Swagger UI directly. I followed this blog and had a test in my side which worked well.
Firstly, I created a new .net 8 web api using VS template and I choose the auth type as Microsoft Identity Platform so that the API will include the codes for using AAD to secure the API. Next I need to modify the appsettings.json with my AAD configurations. Now I need a bearer token in request header so that I could visit the default api endpoint, otherwisze I will get 401 error.

The rest is adding swagger configuraions. Using codes below to replace the default builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();.
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c => {
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "WebApplication1", Version = "v1" });
    c.AddSecurityDefinition("oauth2", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
    {
        Type = SecuritySchemeType.OAuth2,
        Flows = new OpenApiOAuthFlows()
        {
            Implicit = new OpenApiOAuthFlow()
            {
                AuthorizationUrl = new Uri("https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize"),
                TokenUrl = new Uri("https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/token"),
                Scopes = new Dictionary<string, string> {
                    {
                        "api://{client_id}/Tiny.Greet", "API permission description"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
    c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement() {
        {
            new OpenApiSecurityScheme {
                Reference = new OpenApiReference {
                    Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                    Id = "oauth2"
                },
                Scheme = "oauth2",
                Name = "oauth2",
                In = ParameterLocation.Header
            },
            new List < string > ()
        }
    });
});

And using codes below to replace the defaut app.UseSwaggerUI();.
app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
{
    options.OAuthAppName("Swagger Client");
    options.OAuthClientId("client_id");
    options.OAuthClientSecret("client_secret");
    options.OAuthUseBasicAuthenticationWithAccessCodeGrant();
});

In my codes above, I have api scope like this api://client_id/Tiny.Greet. This is the api permission exposed by myself. When I want to secure my API by Azure AD, I need to have such an API permission. If you are not familiar with this part, you might refer to this series turorials.
Then when I go to Swagger UI and click the Authorize button, I will get a dialog like this. Clicking the Authorize button will redirect me to the Microsoft login page and I need to sign in with my account. And I will be able to test the API with a correct bearer token.



The "Authorize" button works for me...that's not what I am trying to achieve. let's say my swagger doc is at https://{host}/swagger/index.html. I want https://{host}/swagger/index.html to reroute to the login flow if the user that tries to access it is not authenticated...not the endpoint

Do you mean you want to add authorization on swagger UI endpoint, which makes the Swagger UI also under protection, right? And after sign in successfully and redirect to https://{host}/swagger/index.html, we will get authorized and we can also test API endpoint successfully?

yup. In your example above only the endpoints are locked...so I can still see there is a /WeatherForecast endpoint and its documentation. I wanted as soon as someone hits https://{host}/swagger/index.html and they are not signed in, to get redirected to the Interactive MSAL Authentication window. At the moment this app is internal but when we plan to externalize it I'd like to be able to lock the documentation behind auth as well, not just the endpoints.

Thank you for your confiramtion, then we need to treat the api project like a web page project and integrate Azure AD authentication UI into the API project, then create a middleware to validate if the request is to the request to swagger UI, if yes, then redirect the request to Microsoft identity platform, just like This is an MVC application, and we define a routing to swagger UI, and we add [Authorize] attribute on this action method.
